# DNN: Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file

Tags: installation, themes, dotnetnuke, skin

I am creating a theme for DNN and my .dnn file components section is:

```
<components>
                    <component type="Skin">
                        <skinFiles>
                            <basePath>Portals\_default\Skins\MyTheme</basePath> 
                            <!-- Target base folder for the component installation. Relative to the root of the DNN installation. -->
                            <skinName>MyTheme</skinName>
                            <skinFile>
                                <path>MyTheme</path> /<!-- Target file folder. Relative to basePath. -->
                                <name>MyTheme.html</name>
                            </skinFile>
                            <skinFile>
                                <path>MyTheme</path> /<!-- Target file folder. Relative to basePath. -->
                                <name>MyTheme.css</name>
                            </skinFile>
                            <skinFile>
                                <path>MyTheme</path> /<!-- Target file folder. Relative to basePath. -->
                                <name>MyTheme.doctype.xml</name>
                            </skinFile>
                        </skinFiles>
                    </component>
                    <component type="ResourceFile">
                        <resourceFiles>
                            <basePath>Portals\_default\Skins\Resources</basePath>
                            <!-- Target folder where the contents of the zip file will be installed. Relative to the root of the DNN installation. -->
                            <resourceFile>
                                <name>Resources.zip</name> <!-- Name of zip file. -->
                            </resourceFile>
                        </resourceFiles>
                    </component>
                </components>
```

while skin files are installed successfully, the zip file creates two errors at the end:

```
StartJob Reading files

Info File MyTheme\gb.png read successfully

Info File MyTheme\MyTheme.css read successfully

Info File MyTheme\MyTheme.dnn read successfully

Info File MyTheme\MyTheme.doctype.xml read successfully

Info File MyTheme\MyTheme.html read successfully

Info File MyTheme\Resources.zip read successfully

EndJob Reading files done.

StartJob Reading Installation Manifest file

Info Reading Package Manifest - Skin - Mzweb.MyTheme

Info Reading Component Manifest - Skin

Info Found valid path (MyTheme) for MyTheme.html.

Info Found valid path (MyTheme) for MyTheme.css.

Info Found valid path (MyTheme) for MyTheme.doctype.xml.

Info Reading Component Manifest - ResourceFile

**Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PDNN\Install\Temp\aqalnba4\Resources.zip

Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PDNN\Install\Temp\aqalnba4\Resources.zip**
```

How to correct these errors?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the file "Resources.zip" is not found within the installation zip.

Are you sure that the file is properly included in your installation package? and not in a sub-folder of any type